# Google Search Console: which of my AMP pages are already indexed?

Tags: google-search-console, accelerated-mobile-page

In the Google Search Console there is an option to see how many AMP pages is already indexed and how many contains some errors. 
When I open a certain error, I can see which one page contains problems. Can I do a similar thing for AMP-friendly indexed pages? Because now I can see e.g. that there is 20 AMP pages indexed by Google and another 15 is not.

**Q:** can I see which of my AMP pages are already indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the appearance of you AMP-Sites in the SC. Just go to "Search Analytics" and activate the "Search Appearance" > AMP Article rich results Filter